# Problema calculando días entre fechas

Tags: java

Estoy programando en **`java 1.6`** y me he encontrado un problema obteniendo la diferencia entre 2 fechas.

me van todas correctamente, salvo cuando hago una prueba entre **Marzo** y **Abril**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static Date deAAAAJJJ_a_Date(Number fechaN) {
    Date fecha = null;
    String fAux = fechaN.toString();                
    SimpleDateFormat formatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDD");
    try {
        fecha = formatFecha.parse(fAux);            
    } catch (ParseException e) {
//      log.error("Mensaje de error",e);
    }
    return fecha;
}

public static int de_Date_a_AAAAJJJ(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat newFormatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDD");
    return Integer.valueOf(newFormatFecha.format(date));
}

public static Date sumarMeses(Date fecha, int meses){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, meses);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

public static int numeroDiasEntreDosFechas(Date fecha1, Date fecha2){
     long startTime = fecha1.getTime();
     long endTime = fecha2.getTime();
     long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
     long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
     return (int)diffDays;
}




public static  void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Se calcula el TAE

    Integer fperCargo = 202020;

    Date fechaActual = deAAAAJJJ_a_Date(fperCargo);
    Date fechaMesSgte = sumarMeses(fechaActual,1);


    System.out.println("fechaActual (juliana):  " + de_Date_a_AAAAJJJ(fechaActual));
    System.out.println("Fecha mes siguiente  : " + de_Date_a_AAAAJJJ(fechaMesSgte));

    Long dias = (Long) ((fechaMesSgte.getTime()-fechaActual.getTime())/86400000);
    System.out.println("dias: " + dias);
    System.out.println("dias: " + numeroDiasEntreDosFechas(fechaActual,fechaMesSgte));



}
```

Si pongo fperCargo = 2020052  (21 de Febrero) -> Lo hace bien (año bisiesto)

fechaActual (juliana):  2020052

Fecha mes siguiente  : 2020081

dias: 29

dias: 29

> Si pongo fpercargo = 2020081 (21 de Marzo) -> Lo hace mal..
>
> deberían de salir 31 (marzo tiene 31 días)
>
> fechaActual (juliana):  2020081
>
> Fecha mes siguiente  : 2020112
>
> dias: 30
>
> dias: 30

Si pongo fperCargo = 2020112 (21 de Abril) -> Lo hace bien..

deben de salir 30 (Abril tiene 30 días)

fechaActual (juliana):  2020112

Fecha mes siguiente  : 2020142

dias: 30

dias: 30

Si pongo fperCargo = 2020142 (21 de Mayo) -> Lo hace bien…

deben de salir 31 (Mayo tiene 31 días)

fechaActual (juliana):  2020142

Fecha mes siguiente  : 2020173

dias: 31

dias: 31

¿Alguien sabe por qué motivo en esa fecha no va correctamente? ¿U otra forma de resolver esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que he visto tu código solicita una fecha que ya la pones directamente, por ejemplo 2020081 y por una parte del código solicita el siguiente mes, después lo resta y te saca cuantos días de diferencia hay del uno al otro. ¿Me equivoco?

Comment: No te equivocas, es así...
Por lo que hemos conseguido ver por internet.. es porque el mes de Marzo tiene menos milisegundos que los otros meses (se adelanta la hora) y no lo calcula bien..

Comment: Al debuggear he visto algo curioso y puede ser la razón, el horario del primero esta en cet Central European Time (CET), pero el segundo esta en cest Central European Summer Time (CEST), no se si tiene que ver pero en Marzo España cambia de hora, ya no se si una mas o una menos, pero puede que eso es lo que te da "Error", el cual no seria un error, te lo estaría haciendo bien.

Comment: Sí.. también lo he visto.. pero claro entonces mi duda es como hacer de una forma limpia este cálculo para java 1.6

Answer (score 4):

Cambia de zona horaria, por ejemplo puedes ponerlo así:

```
public static Date sumarMeses(Date fecha, int meses) {
        Calendar calendar;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, meses);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto!

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si es la solución marcalo como aceptado por favor. Me alegra haberte ayudado.